# Can Territory be an owner of a record?

Tags: ownership, territory, owner, record-owner

While listening to [video "Sharing and Visibility With Salesforce" from Salesforce Apex Hours youtube channel](https://youtu.be/ktJFkWIR2xo?t=1210) at time 20:14, I have seen a slide where it is stated that a Territory can be an owner of a record. However, I cannot find such information in the documentation.
When I try to execute the following code

```
update new Account(Id='0011s00000PMq1tAAD',
OwnerId='0MI1s0000000No5GAE');
```

I receive an error

```
{
  "column": "1",
  "compileProblem": "",
  "compiled": "true",
  "exceptionMessage": "System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 0011s00000PMq1tAAD; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Owner ID: id value of incorrect type: 0MI1s0000000No5GAE: [OwnerId]",
  "exceptionStackTrace": "AnonymousBlock: line 1, column 1",
  "line": "1",
  "success": "false"
}
```

Do I miss any configuration setting or is this statement is completely wrong?
Does it work only with Territory 1.0?
Does it work only with specific objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement is wrong, an owner can only be a user or a queue. And queues cannot be the owner of all types of objects.